# VBA - Browsing, selecting file and saving file as

Tags: ms-access, vba, savefiledialog, save-as

I am creating an access database with forms and reports. in one of my forms I want to be able to go to a folder selecting a file (.pdf, .doc, .xls) and then saving it in a dedicated "attachments" folder.

I know about OLE objects and the attachment functions, but both of these would be saving the attachments within the database perse. I am trying to stay away from this since it is imperative to have readily access to the attachments and also to make the database lighter.

I have been playing in VBA with

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

and

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
```

this is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Select_Save_Click()

Call SelectFile

End Sub


Public Function SelectFile() As String




 Dim FD As FileDialog
 Dim File_Name As String
 Dim path As String

path = "O:\foldername"

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select file to save as attachment"
    If .Show = True Then

        File_Name = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))

        SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)

        new_name = path & File_Name

        .SelectedItems.Item(1).SaveAsFile new_name

        Me.Attach_Save = new_name


    Else
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set FD = Nothing

End With



End Function
```

Comment: Please tell us more about what not working means here.  Error message?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [FileCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as .SaveAsFile method may not work inside the FD object. Plus, [SaveAsFile method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210277%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is primarily associated with the MS Outlook VBA using email attachments.

Also, use `Dir()` on the string variable outside the FD object and not on the variant array `.SelectedItems(1)` inside the FD object.

Finally, notice I add a final back slash in the path string.

```
Dim FD As FileDialog
Dim File_Name As String
Dim path As String

path = "O:\foldername\"

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select file to save as attachment"
    If .Show = True Then
        SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Function        
    End If
End With

File_Name = Dir(SelectFile)       

FileCopy SelectFile, path_name & File_Name

Set FD = Nothing
```